# Recovering a XAMPP database with ibdata1, .frm and .ibd files

Tags: mysql, wordpress, xampp

Thanks for looking!

I've tried pretty much every solution I found online, yet nothing recovered a full database.

My client had a crash of MySQL on her XAMPP, and sent over the mysql/data folder along with WP root directory(it's a WordPress website).

- -she erased the mysql/backup folder
- -I've tried copying ibdata1, .frm and .ibd files into fresh XAMPP, but then I get the "Table doesn't exist in engine" error in PHPMyAdmin

Also tried SysInfo MySQL Database Recovery tool, which extracts the database when pointed to database folder, and without loading ibdata1. If I load ibdata1, tables are empty. If I point the software to the database directory, I get a full database, but with a few weird issues. Some are in wp_posts table(,, instead of ,'',) which brakes the element count, but I hopefully patched it. However, some other things are not showing well, all IDs are like "-9223372036854775555", and slugs have weird characters, like "a-lepsi-jutri��u癮u�".

Post statuses look messed up as well(like "itclosedclosedsta").

On WP side, this manifests as a 404 homepage error. You can access wp-login.php, but after entering the details and trying to login you get redirected to the homepage 404.

When I replace the entire mysql folder in fresh XAMPP with a backup from my client, MySQL won't start.

Have also tried starting it with repair level 1-6, but MySQL still won't start.

Have tried creating a fresh database, adding tables and fields with .frm files, discarding TABLESPACE then copying over only .ibd files and importing TABLESPACE. This works only for empty tables.

Also some other things, but nothing worked so far.

Any WP or DB thoughts - please let me know :)